# CSS and jquery priority problem

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Im a using tabs from the UI-plugin of jquery.
Those tabs dynammically add classes to  `<ul>` and `<ul><li>` tags for visualisation.

However I work in an environment where I only fill part of the website, that is inside a

> `<div id="content">`

block  and other css styles are applied to it.

Since `#content ul li` is more specific than the `ul li` of jquery, the first one takes precedence.

How can  I overcome this problem?

UPDATE : I am aware of !important , that's however not an answer to this question, I hope to find a solution where I don't need to alter jquery-ui's css.  (whatif you would use an online cached version? And if you have to cascade everything you might as well redefine it without !important)

UPDATE 2 : this is definitely not a javascript question, please don't tag it that way.

Answer (score 5):

You can use !important keyword, which makes the selector most important, over cascading values:

```
#content ul li {
    color:red;
}
ul li  {
    color:black !important;
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: +1 for usefull in this context, but I'm afraid not for this particular situation. If I use that I must break in in the CSS of jquery-ui or redefine  all their css-rules...

Comment: besides, in this case, i could easily have written #content ul li {
    color:black;
} too.

Comment: Hmmm, you kind of was looking for !not-so-important word to be used? :). But since such doesn't exist, I can't think any other solution but re-writing jQuery UI declarations in your CSS with !important.

Comment: No, I knew Important, just not a solution to my question